# Split string into key-value pairs where a value can contain a delimiter

Tags: java, split, hashmap

I am trying to split a string into key-value pairs which is very straight forward, but I realized very late that I don't have any validation on my input. the string can contain same delimiter that I am using to split. Not sure if this is possible but can someone please help find a way to split this string into a valid key/value pairs?

The current logic:

```
    String key = "key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3,with,delimeter"
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] entries = key.split(",");
    for(String entry : entries) {
      String[] keyValue = entry.split("=");
      map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
    }
```

Expected output:

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key3:value3,with,delimeter
```

But this code causes `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as there are comma in the last value.

Note: I cannot convert , into a different delimiter as I need to process the string as-is and it can container any character.

Answer (score 0):

Why not split it with `=`, and make the string after the last `,`
the value?

```
String key = "key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3,with,delimeter";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
String[] valueKeys = key.split("=");

// {"key", "value,key", "value"}
String lastKey = valueKeys[0];
for(int i = 1; i < valueKeys.length; i++) {
    String valueKey = valueKeys[i];
    if(i == valueKeys.length - 1) { // It must be the last item in the array
        map.put(lastKey, valueKey);
        break;
    }

    int lastComma = valueKey.lastIndexOf(",");
    map.put(lastKey, valueKey.substring(0, lastComma));
    lastKey = valueKey.substring(lastComma + 1);
}
printMap(map); // Display the map
```

Result:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3,with,delimeter
```

Note: It only works if the key does not contains commas.

Comment: thank you, this also doesn't work if the value contains "=" character correct?

Comment: Yes, if the value contains "=" character, this piece of code will not works. Also, there will be no way to parse that data. Consider this string: `"key=v,al=ue"`, you can't tell if it is `"key"="v,al=ue"` or `"key"="v", "val"="ue"`, right?